# How add new values in a Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

In this example i have a matrix like

```
matr_x <- data.frame(Test=1:5, Score=11:15)
```

[image]

And i want to add another matrix with some new test values

```
add_matrx <- data.frame(Test = c(1,2,5,6,7), Score=16:20)
```

[image]

But, in this another table i have some test numbers that already exist in `matr_x` (numbers: 1, 2 and 5), in this case for these numbers i want to add the scores, getting the final table:

`result_matrx <- data.frame (Test = 1:7, Score = c(27, 29, 13, 14, 33, 19, 20))`

[image]

How can i do it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `rbind` and then `aggregate` ?

```
aggregate(Score ~ Test, rbind(matr_x, add_matrx), sum)

#  Test Score
#1    1    27
#2    2    29
#3    3    13
#4    4    14
#5    5    33
#6    6    19
#7    7    20
```

In `dplyr` it would be

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(matr_x, add_matrx) %>%
   group_by(Test) %>%
   summarise(Score = sum(Score))
```

Comment: You're a geniousssssss hahahaha, thanks!!!!!, I'm my real example i have alot of columns to sum, if i use aggregate(. ~ Test, rbind(matr_x, add_matrx), sum) it works to all columns?

Comment: @skulden yes, if you want to `sum` all other columns then it should work with that.